# In the Poisson Gamma model, how do you show the random variables in the sample are unconditionally dependent?

Tags: probability, bayesian, moment-generating-function

The poisson-gamma model has $n_i |\lambda$ ~ Poiss($\lambda$), with $\lambda$ ~ $gamma(a,b)$. (Prior)

I know that ultimately you can show that unconditionally $n_i$ ~ NegBin($a, (b+1)^{-1}$). And from there it is very easy to show that the $n_i$ are not independent. (By showing that $f_{N_1,N_2}(n_1,n_2) \neq f_{N_1}*f_{N_2}$)

I am curious if there is other ways to show it? I know that a similar rule applies for the MGF namely $M_{N_1,N_2}(t,s) \neq M_{N_1}(t) M_{N_2}(s)$?

Any pointers on how to show this using the MGF would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Further to the discussion below, I have attempted to solve my problem using MGF.

If I denote $S = \Sigma^k_1 n_i$, the sum of the unconditional rv's in the sample of size k. Then:
\begin{equation}E[e^{St}] = E[E[e^{St}|\lambda] =E[E[e^{tn_1|\lambda}]+E[e^{tn_2|\lambda}]+...+E[e^{tn_k|\lambda}]] =E[(E[e^{tn_i|\lambda}])^k] = E[[M_{n_i|\lambda}(t)]^k]
\end{equation}

I don't know where to go from here, nor if I know whether my logic is correct but clearly the product of the MGFs of each unconditional $n_i$ would not be the same as this, as these follow the MGF of a negative binomial, so:

\begin{equation}
M_{n_i}(t) = \left( \frac{(1-b)^{-1}e^t}{1-(1-(1-b)^{-1}e^t)}\right)^a \Rightarrow (M_{n_i}(t))^k = \left( \frac{(1-b)^{-1}e^t}{1-(1-(1-b)^{-1}e^t)}\right)^{ka}
\end{equation}

Thanks.

Comment: Unconditionally they are independent, unless you only draw one $\lambda$ for all $n_i$, which is a special case.  Usually we assume that $\lambda$ varies from one $i$ to another, though.  Is that the assumption you're making?

Comment: In the poisson-gamma model are they? I thought that the $\lambda$ is assumed to be a random variable but because you can show unconditionally that the $n_i$ is a negative binomial, you can then take the expected value of the joint density, and because it is not the same as the product of the expected value of the marginal densities, unconditionally the $n_i$'s are not independent. I apologise if I am only looking at a very specific case here. I appreciate that in practise such a specific model is not useful.

Comment: I strongly suspect you are (implicitly) drawing one $\lambda$ for all $n_i$, rather than one for each $n_i$.  The joint density as a function of $n_1, n_2, \lambda$ leads one to conclude $n_1$ and $n_2$ are not independent, but the joint density as a function of $n_1, n_2, \lambda_1, \lambda_2$ leads one to conclude $n_1$ and $n_2$ are independent.  Sorry for the terseness, it's what happens when I try to make comments brief.

Comment: @mrhappysmile that MGF trick only applies (when you assume independence) for sums of random variables. You aren't summing anything.

Comment: @jbowman Ah I see what you are saying. Yes indeed you have one draw of $\lambda$ for all $n_i$.

Comment: @Taylor I thought, and correct me if I am wrong, that if you observe the joint density of $n_1$ and $n_2$ say $f(n_1,n_2)$ then you can take the joint MGF to be $M(s,t) = E[e^{sN_1 + tN_2}] = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(n_1,n_2) *e^{sN_1 +tN_2} ds dt = M(s) * M(t)$. The point is to show that they are unconditionally dependent, so showing that this is not the case would be sufficient. I am just curious if such a method can be done.

Comment: @mrhappysmile oh you're treating $(n_1,n_2)'$ as a random vector. Then yeah that works

Comment: @Taylor I didn't use exactly what I stated previously, but I thought that my logic made sense to me when I did it. Does it make sense to you - I haven't broken any fundamental laws have I? Thanks!